# Android onCreate flow

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm new to android development and working these days on my first app.
In my activity, in the onCreate function I make 2 function calls , each of the 2 functions has different OnClickListener for different buttons.

Everything works fine , my question is why?

I mean how does it possible that both of the listeners functions "work" on the same time does the app runs in a parallel way? In my head I thought that once the app reach an OnclickListener it will just stop and wait for a buttonClick event but I can see that I can click on button1 and something happens and then I click on Button2 and something else happens (as it should).

I just want an explaination, in general, about the way (flow) the app work/ handles functions of listeners and click events.

Thank you,
Noam

Comment: Instead of posting description if you write some code then that will be more helpful

Comment: check out this: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077351/java-se/events-and-listeners.html

Comment: @Kunu he wants some knowledge not code help .......

Comment: They are `Listeners`...They listen to things...not waiting....you assign a job to them and they are listening until someone call them or the trigger make them to active, then they do what they must do

Comment: @SushilKumar Oh ok, however that down vote is not from my side. I don't discourage newcomers :)

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand what you mean.
button.setOnClickListener(this) means this button just tells the activity that it has a click event. The app won't pause or wait until the button event is executed.
when different widget is clicked, it's own click event will be executed.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's still not clear to me the way that the functions that I'm calling from my OnCreate function are running , do they both run in the same time (parallel)? or one by one? I thought it was one by one but then I saw that both of my button are working when I click on them (each functions handles one button click event) so how could it be one by one? or is it just happening so fast that it is only seem "in the same time"??

Comment: different button has a different click event. when you click one button,it's click event will be executed.the way you understand this is wrong.So I suggest reading an Android book.